# How do I target the content of a element, using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with a piece of code I'm using to build a widget. see below:

```
$(".number-plate").html(function(i, h) { 
   return h.replace(/(ANY|[A-Za-z0-9])/g, '<img src="plate-widget/$1.gif" />'); 
});
```

The problem is that this replaces the entire element, rather than just the content!

Is there a way of targetting the content of `.number-plate` ONLY?

Any help is Greatly Appreciated, Thanks

Comment: when you deal with the h in that function, you deal with the document. try use an html function, like h.html(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract the node, modify it and replace it afterwards, like this:

```
var html = $(".number-plate").html();
$(".number-plate").html(html.replace(/(ANY|[A-Za-z0-9])/g, '<img src="plate-widget/$1.gif" />'));
```

Answer (score 2):

(edit:) If you have more than one element with class `number-plate`, you can use:

```
$(".number-plate").each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.html($this.html().replace(/(ANY|[A-Za-z0-9])/g, '<img src="plate-widget/$1.gif" />'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't happen, the function is only dealing with the content of the tag, not with the tag itself.

You can check that by adding *alert(h);* to your function. If you're getting the whole tag plus its content, I'd say there is a problem with your HTML...